# Matlab - Center of mass of object having only its edge

Tags: matlab, classification, centroid

I'm trying to make an object recognition program using a k-NN classifier. I've got a bunch of images for the training part of the classifier and a bunch of images to recognize. Those images are in grayscale and there's an object per image. The problem is that there's only the edge of the object (not filled), so I don't think using `regionprops(img,'centroid')` will work properly for what I understand...
So how can I get their center of mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**xenoclast**'s answer should be quite clear, just to add something extra.
As you are done creating the binary image from the grayscale image of yours using `im2bw`; if the edge of your the object is a the boundary that covers the object fully, you may use `regionprops(bw,'centroid')` directly without going through `imfill`.

Comment: This worked thank you. I've got another question: I've read that `regionprops(bw,'centroid')`  returns the elements in order of dimension, does it mean that the first element will be the centroid of the smallest element and the last one the centroid of the region?

Comment: The value returned by `regionprops()` is N number of structures. N is the number of connected components (or the number of objects) in the input image. You may look at this http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html?refresh=true#outputarg_stats

You may try this to check out the sequence of the returned structures.
`BW = imread('text.png');
s = regionprops(BW, 'centroid');
imshow(BW)
hold on
for n = 1 : length(s)
plot(s(n).Centroid(:, 1),s(n).Centroid(:,2), 'b*')
pause(0.2)
end`

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to binarise the image with `im2bw`. Then you can use `imfill(img, 'holes')` to turn it from an outline into a filled solid. After that `regionprops` will work as expected.

Comment: It's not working and it has to be automatic, I won't be able to choose the hole to fill while executing the program

Comment: `imfill` on its own spawns the gui but using `imfill(img, 'holes')` is an automatic process (as long as your outline is closed).